# Windows modify permissions in folder - except from specific folders/files

Tags: windows, permissions

In Windows, is it possible to have a directory where users can modify the content of the directory except from specific folders/files?

I do have a directory, let's call it main directory, with permissions set so that users can modify the content of it. This is necessary so they can create, modify and delete folders/files inside. However, I do have a few folders and files that I don't want the users to be able to modify.

I have given the specific folders/files their own permissions (no inheritance) and set its permissions so that the users have no modify permissions. However, they can still modify it (for example delete it) because of the permissions from the main directory.

Furthermore, I have tried to set deny-permissions on the specific folders/files to deny modify permissions for the users on these. But still, they can modify them.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

So I found out here http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-server-2008-r2/107385-deny-delete-permission-not-working.html that a solution would be to set just "Modify" permissions on the main directory applied to "This folder, subfolders and files". Then set a new deny-delete-permission on the main directory applied to "This folder". Then inside the main directory, on the specific folders/files that the users must not modify/delete, set a deny-delete-permission. Then it'll work as the users can create, modify and delete folders/files inside the main directory and they can't modify/delete the main directory or the specific folders/files inside.

Further solutions would be appreciated though.

Answer (score 0):

You're not very clear on what exactly you mean by "modify" but you did give one example, the fact that the user can still delete the file or folder that you're trying to protect.

This happens when the user has `DELETE_CHILD` access to the parent folder, described as "Delete subfolders and files" in the Explorer GUI or as `DC` in the command-line `icacls` tool.  If you have given the users "Full Control" over the folder, this includes `DELETE_CHILD` access, which takes precedence over the permissions on the child object(s).  If I remember correctly, this access right also allows the child object(s) to be moved.

If you are assigning the parent folder permissions in the GUI, use the "Modify" option instead of the "Full Control" option.  (This would probably be the most sensible option anyway, because it also stops the users from changing the folder permissions.)

From the command line you would do the same thing by using `(M)` rather than `(F)`.

Better still, grant the users only the "Create Files" and "Create Folders" right on the parent directory, plus a full (or modify) permission set to apply only to child objects, something like this:

```
icacls parentdirectory /grant MyUsers:(RX,WD,AD) /grant MyUsers:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
```

Comment: The users doesn't have "Full Control". In the GUI it says "Special". This permission is set on the main directory and is applied to "This folder, subfolders and files". This "Special" is exactly the same as "Modify" except from one thing and that is the "Delete" option is not checked but the "Delete subfolders and files" is. This is to allow the users to create, modify and delete folders/files inside the main directory. However, there are a few folders and files inside the main directory that I don't want the users to be able to modify/delete.

Comment: The "delete subfolders and files" gives the users access to delete *all* subfolders and files, regardless of their permissions.  You don't need it if you only want them to be able to delete subfolders and files that they have delete permission for.

Comment: To put it another way, in order to delete a file or subfolder you need *either* the "delete subfolders and files" permission on the parent *or* the "delete" permission on the child, not both.